# Check if proxy is working

Tags: java, proxy

I am trying to check wether proxy servers are working. I'm using this code, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly. It returns true, but when i try to use the proxy, the program times out.

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("ip", port));
int timeout = 9000;
URL url = new URI("http://google.com/").toURL();
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection(proxy); 
connection.setConnectTimeout((int) timeout); 
connection.setReadTimeout((int) timeout);       
long start = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
connection.connect(); 
long delay = System.currentTimeMillis() - start; 
return delay <= timeout;
```

Thanks

Comment: Times out doing what? But this code doesn't make sense. The delay cannot possibly be greater than the timeout, otherwise an exception would have been thrown.

Answer (score 2):

Just try to use the proxy in the normal way as you need it, and handle the exceptions as they arise.

Tricks like this are essentially attempts to predict the future. They cannot possibly work.

Comment: But there are many public proxies, most of them are dead, so need to filter out the good ones somehow.

Comment: A dead public proxy isn't a proxy at all. If you have a *list* of public proxies many of which are dead, *cull the list.*